# Service Bus Topic Doesn't Receive Messages When Using Newtonsoft to Deserialize

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net, servicebus

I am trying to deserialize messages from a service bus topic created as follows (.NET 4.6.1):

```
SubscriptionClient ServiceBusClient =
        SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString
        (ConnectionString, Topic, SubscriptionName);
```

I then create the on message method as follows:

```
 OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
 options.AutoComplete = false;
 options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

 ServiceBusClient.OnMessage((message) =>
 {
     try
     {
         Stream stream = message.GetBody<Stream>();
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
         string payload = reader.ReadToEnd();
         dynamic deserialize = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(payload);

         var avl = AvlDatum.Parser.ParseFrom(Convert.FromBase64String(deserialize.body));

         /* do other stuff here */
         message.Complete();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
                message.Abandon();
     }
}, options);
```

Using this code however I receive absolutely no messages. I thought something was wrong with the topic but if I comment out the line with the dynamic object it receives the messages fine. Why am I not able to use the Newtonsoft Parser/dynamic objects inside an OnMessage delegate? Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the payload variable contain anything? Could you post the code that places the message on the queue?

Comment: Yeah, the payload looks like this:

    {"body":"testbody","customProperties":{"protoType":"AVL","version":"0.1.0","id":"testid","rootType":"AvlDatum"}}

I'm only really interested in the body. The code that creates the message is not available to me unfortunately, I was only given the endpoint. Not a big deal I guess, I'll just have to find another way to deserialize it :)

Comment: Is it necessary to use a dynamic? Could you create a class that matches the properties of the message and use JsonConvert.Deserialize?

Comment: I just tried JsonConvert.Deserialize<RootObject>(payload) and it has the same issue. However, I think I've found the issue. I turned on all exception messages and am now getting this: The assembly with display name 'Newtonsoft.Json' failed to load. It's obviously some issue with the package or version of Newtonsoft. I'm sure I can figure it out from here, thanks for the help!

Comment: It's working now, silly error (different versions of Newtonsoft.Json). Pretty annoying that the exception didn't show up until I changed my exception setting in visual studio. Thanks again.